# How to suppress empty backreferences?

Tags: back-referencing

I am using the `backref` package to provide backreferences from my bibliography to the text, working as expected. I need to add one entry to the bibliography, however, that is not cited in the paper, as such. `\nocite{}` does just that, adding the entry to the bibliography, but I now get an empty "Cited on page:" as well. Any way to suppress that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to figure it out:

```
\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{
\ifcase #1 {~}
\or {page~#2}
\else {pages~#2}        
\fi}
```

If there is not a single reference, nothing is printed, "page" if there is one, plural if there are more than one.